# JavaScript textarea calculate

Tags: javascript

The point is that you create a table of your own size. Is there any possible way that when I press "Calc" button it calculates number in this table? Imagine all the rows and columns are filled with random numbers. I want to calculate numbers in same row. First you create a table, then you fill it with values and than you calculate all values between each other.
This is my code:

```js
function createTable() {
  var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
  var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
  var tbody = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
      tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += '<input type="text" name="something">';
      tbody += '</td>'
    }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
  }
  var tfooter = '</table>';
  document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <label>col: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />
  <label>row: <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols"/></label><br/>
  <input name="generate" type="button" value="Make table!" onclick='createTable();' />
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
<input name="calculate" type="button" value="Calc" />
```

Comment: You're going to need to define, "calculate numbers." The term, "calculate," is pretty broad...

Comment: So for example i make a table 2x2. Then I put in number like 1,2,3,4. So 1 and 2 in a row and 3 and 4 in a row. Then I want to press calc which call a function that calculates 1*2 and 3*4.

Comment: Ok, you need to edit your question and replace all references to the term, "calculate," with an explanation that you want all numbers in a row multiplied together. Then, remove the only question you've actually asked ("Is there any possible way..."), show what you've attempted so far, and ask questions about specific issues you're running into as you try.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createTable() {
  let num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  let num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
  let table = '<table id="my-table" border="1" style="width:100%;">';

  for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
      table += '<td><textarea style="width:95%;"></textarea></td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
  }
  table += '</table>';
  document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = table;
}

function calcValues() {
  let result = 0;
  let table = document.getElementById('my-table');
  if (table) {
    let textareas = table.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    if (textareas.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
        let textarea = textareas[i];
        let value = textarea.value;
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
          result *= parseInt(value);
        } else {
          textarea.value = 'That was not a number!';
        }
      }
      if (result != 0) document.getElementById('calcResult').innerHTML = '<p>The result is: ' + result.toString() + '</p>';
    }
  } else alert('Make a table!');
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows" placeholder="Columns" />
  <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols" placeholder="Rows" />
  <input name="generate" type="button" value="Make table!" onclick="createTable()" />
</form>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:5px 0;border:1px solid black;min-height:10px;">Create a table first!</div>
<input name="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate Values!" onClick="calcValues()" />
<p id="calcResult"></p>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for that. But what i need is more complicated...my question wasnt probably good enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach that does the multiplication for each row and adds the result to the existing table as a new column.

```js
function createTable() {
  var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
  var theader = '<table border="1" id="table">\n';
  var tbody = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
      tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += '<input type="text" name="something">';
      tbody += '</td>'
    }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
  }
  var tfooter = '</table>';
  document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}

function calculate() {
  // get the table
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  if (!table) {
    alert("No table made yet");
    return;
  }
  table = table.children[0];
  // loop through rows
  for (var i = 0; i < table.children.length; i++) {
    if (table.children[i].tagName == "TR") {
      var row = table.children[i];

      var result = row.children[0].children[0].value;
      var result_cell = null;

      // loop through cols
      for (var j = 1; j < row.children.length; j++) {
        if (row.children[j].children[0].name != "result") {
          if (!isNaN(parseInt(row.children[j].children[0].value))) {
            result *= parseInt(row.children[j].children[0].value);
          }
        } else {
          result_cell = row.children[j];
        }

      }
      
      // create new result cell if we don't already have one
      if (result_cell == null) {
        result_cell = document.createElement("TD");
      }
      // update set the value (used an input type)
      result_cell.innerHTML = '<input style="border-color:red;" type="text" name="result" value="' + result + '" readonly>'
      row.appendChild(result_cell);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="tablegen">
  <label>row: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />
  <label>col: <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols"/></label><br/>
  <input name="generate" type="button" value="Make table!" onclick='createTable();' />
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
<input name="calculate" type="button" value="Calc" onclick='calculate();' />
```